# How to reference a component of an object in another Scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't really get help from other posts on this topic, so I search for help focused on my case. I try to make a gamemanager in a scene only for itself. I made it DontDieOnLoad. Now I try to get the script of an gameobject from another scene, but it doesn't get the object.

*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Spaceship _spaceship;

    private void Start()
    {
        _spaceship = GameObject.Find("Spaceship").GetComponent<Spaceship>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            _spaceship.Shoot();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            _spaceship.MoveLeft();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            _spaceship.MoveRight();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mark objects **DontDestroyOnLoad** it should still be there when you load into another scene.

Make sure a **Spaceship** object exists in the hierarchy with the exact name.

You could improve the code by using **FindObjectsOfType**:

```
_spaceship = Object.FindObjectsOfType<Spaceship>();
```

And some error handling:

```
if(_spaceship == null) Debug.Log("There's no spaceship!");
```